# Does spring return error codes when error appears?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, http

My question is does spring return error codes when error appears? Like I'm returning "200 OK" if everything is ok and if it's not I'm not doing anything. what does Spring return in cases like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally any unhandled exception thrown when processing a web-request causes the server to return an HTTP 500 response.
For more info, please refer [Spring documentation on Exception Handling](https://spring.io/blog/2013/11/01/exception-handling-in-spring-mvc)